# What are the advantages/disadvantages of creating tag synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

What are the advantages and disadvantages of creating tag synonyms?

For example, when I was viewing the tag information, I came across with a synonym for a tag. The difference was just making it singular form.

Example:

- tag `selectors`
- synonym `selector`

So are there any advantages and/or disadvantages to the community for a tag synonym?

Comment: This is the key quality of life improvement, because it means that new users can no longer accidentally pollute the tag pool by adding or contributing to yet another oddball variant of an existing tag. Again. And Again. And Again…

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Too broad, in my opinion, but not dupe: OP here is **NOT** asking "What are tag synonyms?". (I appear in the Close voters list because I cast a "Too Broad" vote)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose of tag synonyms is to avoid fragmentation. If some questions were tagged [selector](/questions/tagged/selector) and some [selectors](/questions/tagged/selectors) then you would have to search both tags to find all the questions. Some people would tag with both tags, and so on. This is even more significant when the synonyms aren't just the plural and singular forms of a word, but words that are spelled very differently. For example, on travel the [security](/questions/tagged/security) tag has synonyms [theft](/questions/tagged/theft) and [crime](/questions/tagged/crime). If you tag your question [crime](/questions/tagged/crime) it will appear tagged [security](/questions/tagged/security). This spares people having to wonder whether their question is more about theft than crime, for example.

The disadvantage is that sometimes people are confused by synonyms and think someone changed their tags, and get offended. This is a small disadvantage to be sure.